# Need help tweaking Fiddle code to Collapse/Expand Divs using Javascript and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yrshaikh/gqtxP/

How can this be edited so that the lines *collapsed* by default instead of expanded?

I just want everything to start out collapsed, rather than expanded. What should be changed in the code?

(Just getting back into web dev... really newby.)

Below is a copy of the code from fiddle, in case the link doesn't work.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span id="expandAll" class="links">Expand All</span>
    <span id="collapseAll" class="links">Collapse All</span>    
</div>

<div id="header1" class="header">
    <img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/bullet_toggle_minus.png" />
    <span>Sachin Tendulkar</span>
</div>
<div id="description1" class="description">
    Sachin Ramesh Tendulkar is an Indian cricketer widely acknowledged as one of the greatest batsmen in One Day International[2] and second only to Don Bradman in the all time greatest list in Test cricket
</div>

<div id="header2" class="header">
    <img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/bullet_toggle_minus.png" />
    <span>Rahul Dravid</span>
</div>
<div id="description2" class="description">
    Rahul Dravid is a former Indian cricketer, who captained the national Test and One Day International (ODI) teams. Born in a Marathi family, he started playing cricket at the age of 12 and later represented the state team at the under-15, under-17 and under-19 levels.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{font-family:Arial;}
.header img{position:relative; top:10px;}
.header { font-weight:bold; padding-bottom:10px;cursor:pointer;}
.links {color:#3366CC;cursor:pointer;}
.links:hover {border-bottom:1px solid #3366CC;}
```

Javascript:

```
var mImg = "http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/bullet_toggle_minus.png";
var pImg = "http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/bullet_toggle_plus.png";
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#expandAll").click(function(){
        $(".description").slideDown();
        $(".header img").attr("src", mImg)
    });

    $("#collapseAll").click(function(){
        $(".description").slideUp();
        $(".header img").attr("src", pImg)
    });

    $("#header1").click(function(){
        var currentState = $("#description1").css("display");
        if(currentState = "block"){
            $("#description1").slideUp();
            $("#header1 img").attr("src", pImg)
        }
        else{
            $("#description1").slideDown();
            $("#header1 img").attr("src", mImg)
        }
    });

    $("#header2").click(function(){
        var currentState = $("#description2").css("display");
        if(currentState = "block"){
            $("#description2").slideUp();
            $("#header2 img").attr("src", pImg)
        }
        else{
            $("#description2").slideDown();
            $("#header2 img").attr("src", mImg)
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(".description").hide();

Straight after the document has been loaded will mean anyone without Javascript enabled won't have the descriptions hidden on page load (progressive enhancment)

You can also add a slideToggle() in the expandCollapse function to alternate between the two states of slide up and slide down.

Finally you could switch between the two images with the help of two classes one for the plus image and one for the minus image you could then alternate between them using toggleClass() and addClass() and removeClass()

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".description").hide();
        
        $("#expandAll").click(function(){
            $(".description").slideDown();
            $(".header").removeClass("pImg").addClass("mImg");
        });
        
        $("#collapseAll").click(function(){
            $(".description").slideUp();
            $(".header").removeClass("mImg").addClass("pImg");
        });
        
        $("#header1, #header2").click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("mImg").next().slideToggle();
        });
});
```

```css
body{font-family:Arial;}
.header img{position:relative; top:10px;}
.header { font-weight:bold; padding-bottom:10px;cursor:pointer;}
.links {color:#3366CC;cursor:pointer;}
.links:hover {border-bottom:1px solid #3366CC;}
.header { padding-left: 36px; line-height: 32px; margin-top: 5px;}
.pImg { background: url("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/bullet_toggle_plus.png") no-repeat;}
.mImg { background: url("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/bullet_toggle_minus.png") no-repeat;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <span id="expandAll" class="links">Expand All</span>
    <span id="collapseAll" class="links">Collapse All</span>    
</div>

<div id="header1" class="header pImg">
    <span>Sachin Tendulkar</span>
</div>
<div id="description1" class="description">
    Sachin Ramesh Tendulkar is an Indian cricketer widely acknowledged as one of the greatest batsmen in One Day International[2] and second only to Don Bradman in the all time greatest list in Test cricket
</div>

<div id="header2" class="header pImg">
    <span>Rahul Dravid</span>
</div>
<div id="description2" class="description">
    Rahul Dravid is a former Indian cricketer, who captained the national Test and One Day International (ODI) teams. Born in a Marathi family, he started playing cricket at the age of 12 and later represented the state team at the under-15, under-17 and under-19 levels.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just set the below in your CSS

```
.description{
    display:none;
}
```

Also you can simplify your click handeler logic to :

```
    $(".header").click(function(){
        var elm= $(this).nextAll('.description').first()
        if($(elm).is(':visible')){
           $(elm).slideUp(); 
           $(this).find('.myImg').attr("src", pImg);
        }
        else{
           $(elm).slideDown(); 
           $(this).find('.myImg').attr("src", mImg);
        }
    });
```

**Below is the full working code:**

```js
var mImg = "http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/bullet_toggle_minus.png";
var pImg = "http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/bullet_toggle_plus.png";
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $("#expandAll").click(function(){
        $(".description").slideDown();
        $(".header img").attr("src", mImg)
    });
    
    $("#collapseAll").click(function(){
        $(".description").slideUp();
        $(".header img").attr("src", pImg)
    });
        
    $(".header").click(function(){
        var elm= $(this).nextAll('.description').first()
        if($(elm).is(':visible')){
           $(elm).slideUp(); 
           $(this).find('.myImg').attr("src", pImg);
        }
        else{
           $(elm).slideDown(); 
           $(this).find('.myImg').attr("src", mImg);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body{font-family:Arial;}
.header img{position:relative; top:10px;}
.header { font-weight:bold; padding-bottom:10px;cursor:pointer;}
.links {color:#3366CC;cursor:pointer;}
.links:hover {border-bottom:1px solid #3366CC;}

.description{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <span id="expandAll" class="links">Expand All</span>
    <span id="collapseAll" class="links">Collapse All</span>    
</div>

<div id="header1" class="header">
    <img  class="myImg" src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/bullet_toggle_plus.png" />
    <span>Sachin Tendulkar</span>
</div>
<div id="description1" class="description">
    Sachin Ramesh Tendulkar is an Indian cricketer widely acknowledged as one of the greatest batsmen in One Day International[2] and second only to Don Bradman in the all time greatest list in Test cricket
</div>

<div id="header2" class="header">
    <img class="myImg" src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/bullet_toggle_plus.png" />
    <span>Rahul Dravid</span>
</div>
<div id="description2" class="description">
    Rahul Dravid is a former Indian cricketer, who captained the national Test and One Day International (ODI) teams. Born in a Marathi family, he started playing cricket at the age of 12 and later represented the state team at the under-15, under-17 and under-19 levels.
</div>
```